# faced error when upgrade sdk version from 28 to 29

Tags: android, cordova, ionic4, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I encounter permission denied issue when copy file from Internal storage or SD Card to application data directory. The same issue happen when uploading the from Internal storage or SD Card.

I tried to build the same source code in android target sdk 28, everything working well, but the function is not working in android target sdk 29. I also tried to install target sdk 28 in devices and re-install with target sdk 29 WITHOUT uninstall target sdk 28. My application working well in this scenario.

Do any can guide me, how can i amend my config to prevent the permission denied issue?

```
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Install cordova plugin for android X

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-androidx ionic cordova
> plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx npm i cordova-plugin-androidx
>
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter ionic
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter npm i
> cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter

2. Edit config.xml for sdk

> ```
> <preference name="android-buildToolsVersion" value="29.0.0" />
> <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
> <preference name="android-compileSdkVersion" value="29" />
> <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />
> <preference name="android-supportLibVersion" value="28.0.0" />
> <preference name="android-googlePlayServicesAuthVersion" value="16.0.1" />
> ```

3. Remove existing android platform, add add android platform 9.0.0 +
4. Edit application tag in AndroidManifest.xml, add attribute below

> android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"